# Sharing one JavaScript file among several domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

**Problem definition:**

- Server is an embedded system with *no access to Internet*.
- Each server is managed by web interface which uses JavaScript.
- Each server has a local copy of JQuery library.
- Clients (browsers) are connected to embedded systems (servers) via a *very slow connection*.
- Clients have the latest browsers (HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript 1.8.5)
- Clients are not connected to Internet either.
- Clients can't access multiple servers at the same time (servers are in distant locations and most probably a client can only access one server and nothing else, but later that day the client may go to another location and connect to another server).
- Each server has an IP address (not necessarily in the same range) and *no DNS name*.
- Every time the client connects to an embedded server, it fetches all the files including the huge JQuery library (huge=~90KB)

**Question:**
The JQuery library is too big for this slow connection but one-time download is acceptable. However, we don't want the clients to download it every time they connect to each new server. The JQuery on all these devices is the same. But apparently the browser cache is domain based. How can we cache the JQuery library so that the client doesn't have to download the JQuery every time it connects to a new server?

Comment: Uh ... 90KB is too big a download? What kind of connection is that? 3600 baud?

Comment: 9600 bits per sec. It's a special embedded device working deep under ground and in hard to reach areas. The devices don't see each other and normally are not connected to any other network.

Answer (score 1):

just link to it in one place...

for example, if you have a single server, http://1.2.3.4/ that you want to designate as your CDN, put jQuery on it, and link to it in your scripts using `<script src="http://1.2.3.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: clients cannot see all servers and we don't have a central repository. assume the servers are deep inside the ground and a client can see only 1 or 2 servers. I just added this to the problem definition as well.

Comment: sounds like you have a very specialised setup. if the clients are just as specialised, a possible solution is to run a web server on the clients themselves and keep common scripts available there. then the servers would link to, say, `<script src="http://127.0.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. if that's not the right answer either, I think the question needs further explanation

Comment: In simple words: how can a client cache a resource (in this case a script) to be used in another domain? localStorage[] may come handy.

Answer (score 1):

you could link it to the ip in your link tag. The server does not have to have access to that access  or anything, and so all the clients will geht the jquery from the same server all the time and so it is cached.

Comment: clients cannot see all servers and we don't have a central repository. assume the servers are deep inside the ground and a client can see only 1 or 2 servers. I just added this to the problem definition as well.

Comment: well if you had internet acccess could do that there, but as you havent this is tricky. If this is a fixed set of clients it might be possible to put the file on the harddisk and link it with src="C:\" or src="file:\\".

Comment: yeah I know. It has kept my mind busy for a week already. I may be able to load store the library in localStorage[] in the client browser but then how can I load it into the page next time it connects to another server? Can I insert a <script> tag in the HTML and pump the jQuery library from localStorage to that tag?

Comment: didnt know that before at all, but it seems that it is not possible to access the localstorage of the other servers (but you can try it with a simple test string or something). If that would work it would be a nice and simple solution. If you load it in a iframe or something it should work there, but i think you cant access the iframe from the outsite because .. again it is on another server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution: All your customers must edit their `/etc/hosts` file (Google for where you can find it on Windows) and put a line like this in their config:

```
1.2.3.4 jquery-from-closest-server.com
```

Each client must figure out the closest server which has jQuery and replace `1.2.3.4` with its IP address.

In your HTML code, always use the link `http://jquery-from-closest-server.com/jquery.js`

To be safe, you may want to register `jquery-from-closest-server.com` for those customers which do have Internet access.

When the browser asks for the file, it will use `/etc/hosts` to resolve the IP address. Since the domain name will be the same for all your embedded devices (changes in the IP address are ignored by the browser), the script will be downloaded once for all clients.

Note that this means you can never upgrade to a newer version of jQuery. The problem is that you'd have to replace it on all embedded devices at the same time because there is no telling from which server the customers are downloading it from.

If that bothers you (and it will in about four months after you discovered the first serious bug), here is another solution: Instead of serving the HTML from your embedded device, distribute a static web app (a set of HTML files and JavaScript) which customer can install in their desktop. Use AJAX and `iframe`s to replace parts of the static web app with data from your embedded device.

Advantages:

- very fast (no downloads at all)
- only little code on the embedded device
- easy upgrade strategy
- No deadlocks when you need to upgrade either the embedded devices or your controller app.

**[EDIT]** PS: Consider to compress jQuery with gzip. That leaves you with a 33KB file. All HTML5 browsers can decode compressed files, you just have to tell them by setting the necessary HTTP headers.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the sophisticated solution. But for several reasons our specific clients-secotr can't use that. However, someone with a similar question may benefit from your answer. JQuery mobile is a better fit for our project since it has a smaller size and can do almost everything we need from JQuery. http://zeptojs.com/ is also another suitable replacement. Also JQuip is a stripped down version of JQuery that can help our specific project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no standard way to include JQuery in our project so we chose to replace JQuery with a smaller similar library. These are the options:

- JQuery mobile is a better fit for our project since it has a smaller size and can do almost everything we need from JQuery.
- Zepto.js is also another suitable replacement.
- JQuip is a stripped down version of JQuery that can help our specific project.